# Make Google Chrome "forget" zoom level once a tab is closed

Tags: google-chrome

If I visit a site and zoom in/out (CTRL+Scroll Up/Down) Chrome seems to remember that zoom level for that specific site. Is there a way to make it so that it doesn't remember and is always at the original size when a new tab is opened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is a really old question, but I was googling for a way to do the same and found an extension called [Per Tab Zoom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dnhodapkogdjinogphlafimejpmahoam) that can make <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+Scroll Wheel to zoom tabs independently of each other.

When you close a tab, its zoom setting is forgotten.
You can customize a few shortcuts to perform the kind of zoom you want. "Per tab" zoom is forgotten when the tab is closed and "per domain" zoom is remembered for all pages in that domain.

[image]

Comment: That extension requires you to download and install an exe, hard pass.

Comment: @DonWilson, unfortunately there no other extension that can remap those shortcuts, so there's no choice. It's this or nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Upon further discovery, this was reported back in May as having been present in Incognito mode, too. My testing using Chrome 7.0.517.44 shows that it does not happen in Incognito, although I did a purge within Incognito, too. In any event, in REGULAR mode, Chrome stores your domains and zoom levels in the Preferences file (found, on Win 7 Pro 64 bit, at c:/Users/NAME/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default) whether you purge your history or not. You can open this with Notepad and manually edit out the listings. Was interesting to see everything that was listed in there, including ancient browsing history. This file also includes some entries for "most visited blacklist" but these are hash files, and not overtly-listed domain names like the zoom level listings. This is definitely a bug in Chrome, as purging your history does not remove these entries from Preferences. This, then, begs the question of what other files maintain URL info in them, too. For now, the only solution is to use Incognito, or remember to never zoom in Chrome regular mode.

Comment: Good information Lenny, thanks. I marking this as accepted being that it is considered an issue and there really isn't a solution yet.

Comment: The location of this file in OS X is `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences`

Answer (score 2):

This is a real problem because it shows that Chrome still retains browsing data even after purging the history and all previous stuff. Despite a purge, your zoom level is retained for the domain, which means somewhere in the guts of Chrome is a listing of all domains and their zoom levels, which never gets purged. I have not tested this in Incognito mode. Google needs to fix this, or really reveal what gets retained in its browser after a purge.